# ffmpeg exact start and end times

Tags: ffmpeg

I've searched a lot but didn't find what I nedd.
I use this command:

```
ffmpeg -ss <start> -i <SrcFile> -t <duration> -c copy <DstFile>
```

to copy a part of the video, but the output file start time and duration may differ than "start" and "duration" specified.
I understand that ffmpeg seeks to the nearest Keyframe and that precise seeking to a timestamp is not possible unless re-encoding the video (I tried that but the output video losses quality!).
It's important to me to know the exact start and end timestamp that ffmpeg use to generate the output, because I use this info to adjust subtitle timing.
Is there any way to make ffmpeg report start timestamp and end timestamp?
Or else: Is there any way to know the previous and next keyframes to specific Timestamp, so I can adjust the video cut markers in my project to fit nearest keyframes?
Thanks.

Update:
- Is it possible to seek to the second keyframe, and to the keyframe before the last one?
- what is the time interval between 2 keyframes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run

```
ffmpeg -start_at_zero -copyts -ss <start> -t <duration> -i <SrcFile> -c copy <DstFile>
```

Then check

```
ffprobe Dstfile
```

The start time will be the starting timestamp from the source. Start time + duration gives you the end time. Once you have this info, run

```
ffmpeg -i Dstfile -c copy FinalFile
```

to have a file with start time 0.

Comment: Tanks very much, Mulvya. It worked.
So, if I may ask:
1- why ffmpeg doesn't output this info directly to standard output?.. It will save us trouble and time!
2- the output video from this step:
ffmpeg -i Dstfile -c copy FinalFile
takes about 10 seconds to play in MPC-HC, While the temp file starts fast and works perfectly. Why is this, and what is the need for the last command in first place?

Comment: 3- I still have a problem: Sometimes ffmpeg seeks to the previous keyframe, so output video could contain some unwanted seconds from the original video!.. Now I know the offset time of the temp output video, so I want to fix this in the final output video, by seeking the next keyframe (i.e. the second keyframe in the tmpfile.). Is this possible?
Thanks again.

Comment: - Is it possible to seek to the second keyframe, and to the keyframe before the last one?
- what is the time interval between 2 keyframes?